# query xml using xsd attributes

Tags: xml, linq, xsd

I have an XML document that includes an inline XSD (shown fully below). the problem is that i need to search the XML content using attributes imputed from the XSD - preferably in LINQ (XPATH also works).

So, in the example below, I would want to find the element `CATALOG_NAME` by inferring off the XSD the `sql:field` attribute value `CATALOG_NAME` and then matching it against the real element name in the XML document `CATALOG_NAMEC00`. Once I have the element, I want its value.

I see numerous examples of XSD validation and examples of querying the XSD itself. In the end, I am looking for the "merged" capability without some manual lookup hack.

Is this possible?

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxmla="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/xmla">
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="row" type="row" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:simpleType name="uuid">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}" />
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:complexType name="xmlDocument">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:any />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="row">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element sql:field="CATALOG_NAME" name="CATALOG_NAMEC00" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xsd:element sql:field="SCHEMA_NAME" name="SCHEMA_NAMEC01" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xsd:element sql:field="CUBE_NAME" name="CUBE_NAMEC02" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xsd:element sql:field="DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME" name="DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAMEC03" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xsd:element sql:field="HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME" name="HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAMEC04" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
    <row>
      <CATALOG_NAMEC00>AGS PLANUNG_PA</CATALOG_NAMEC00>
      <CUBE_NAMEC02>Aktionsplan</CUBE_NAMEC02>
      <DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAMEC03>[Planstand]</DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAMEC03>
      <HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAMEC04>[Planstand].[Planstand]</HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAMEC04>
    </row>
  </root>
</return>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this XPath:

```
//*[local-name()=//*:element[@*:field='CATALOG_NAME']/@name]
```

This is XPath 2.0, so I used `*` as the namespace prefix, but you can declare namespaces and use whatever prefix you want.